# Rebinding key in AUCTeX which takes other argument

Tags: emacs, auctex

In AucTeX there are two useful commands:
`C-c C-e` for inserting the environment and `C-u C-c C-e` for changing the environment at the point to another one. For me the latter command is quite inconvenient, so I would like to rebind it to something simpler, lets say, to `C-c e` I've tried to do that in a standard way:

```
    (defun my-tex-mode-hook ()
    (local-set-key ((kbd "C-c e") (kbd "C-u C-c C-e")))
    (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'my-tex-mode-hook)
```

but the command `C-c e` does not ask for the argument, i.e., which environment I want to choose. Instead it always changes to default `itemize` environment. Moreover, it works only one time per emacs session.

Probably, my question fits better for the Emacs community, then sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "latex"
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c e")
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (LaTeX-environment 1))))
```

I'm assuming you have Emacs 24.4 or newer versions, otherwise this code will need to be slightly changed (`with-eval-after-load` was introduced in that version).

Comment: In my Emacs 24.5.1 I've got the following error message: `Symbol's value as variable is void: LaTeX-mode-map`

Comment: `with-eval-after-load` is needed to evaluate the code after the package has been loaded (and the mode map defined), I really can't understand why you get that error, doesn't happen to me :-/

Comment: Neither me do. But it started to work when I put your code without the first line `(with-eval-after-load "latex"` instead of my command `(local-set-key ((kbd "C-c e") (kbd "C-u C-c C-e")))`. Thanks! How I survived earlier without that command...